# Picking a word from a scanner input

Tags: java, string, forms, search, java.util.scanner

How do you pick a word from a string or scanner input, say for instance a search engine search?

I looked up indexOf() for a string but I’m not finding how to make a public void word class from finding a word from a line of text. Hoping every word can be a variable.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you've written so far, and to explain where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

From what you asked this is what I understood. Main class with a new FindWord object, a text and the method of the object. Class named FindWord with a method called searchFor() with two parameters. The first parameter is the word you want to find and the second parameter is the text you want to be searched.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // New object FindWord
        FindWord find = new FindWord();
        // Text to search if a word is contained
        String text = "This is a simple text to search for a word";
        // Calling the method to search for a word in the text above
        find.searchFor("simple", text);
    }
}

public class FindWord {
    public void searchFor(String word, String text){
        // Add every word of text in a list
        String string[] = text.split(" ");
        for (int i=0; i<string.length; i++){
            // if the word is in the list then print the word and the position where it is
            if (word.equals(string[i])) {
                System.out.println("The word " + word + " found at position " + i + " of text");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

package exceptions;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ChatBot {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String [] keywords = {"Bad", "Good", "Great", "Sad"};

    System.out.println("How are you feeling today?");
    String response = input.nextLine();

    // [I] [am] [doing] [good]
    String [] responseArray = response.split(" ");

    for (int i = 0; i < responseArray.length; i++) {
        String word = responseArray[i];

        for(int j = 0; j < keywords.length; j++){
            if(word.equalsIgnoreCase(keywords[j])){
                String matchedKeyword  = keywords[j];
                if(matchedKeyword.equalsIgnoreCase("good")
                        || matchedKeyword.equalsIgnoreCase("great")){
                    System.out.println("Super! Happy for you!");
                }

                if(matchedKeyword.equalsIgnoreCase("bad")
                        || matchedKeyword.equalsIgnoreCase("sad")){
                    System.out.println("I'm sorry, hope you feel better soon!");
                }
            }
        }

    }


}
```

}